# Populate from a nested local field with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I have a collection of users, each user looks like this:

```
{
  name: "Chris",
  library:[
    {
       year:"2019",
       books:[
         _id:"101",
         _id:"102",
         _id:"103"
       ]
    },
    {
       year:"2020",
       books:[
         _id:"201",
         _id:"202"
       ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and a collection books that looks like this:

```
[
  {
     _id:"101",
     title:"The fault in our stars",
     writer:"John Green"
  },
  {
     _id:"102",
     title:"Hunger Games",
     writer:"Suzanne Collins"
  },

  etc...
]
```

I'm trying to populate the books into the user.

Is there a way using aggregation pipeline to do it, without having to look it up manually (using find for example)?
I already tried with $lookup but I couldn't specify the nested localField.